# MySQLi_STMT sql query access

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to know how to view the SQL query held by a MySQLi_STMT object.

I'm using an object of type MySQLi_STMT and I want to inspect the SQL statement associated with the object. I set the SQL query using the

```
   mysqli_stmt::prepare ( string $query )
```

function. I then call the

```
   mysqli_stmt::bind_param( string $types , array $params )
```

function to bind parameters in the query. I want to ensure that the binding was done correctly by inspecting the mysqli_stmt object.  However, upon viewing the class's instance fields, none of them hold the newly-bound query. $errno is 0 and $sqlstate is '00000' so it doesn't seem like there's an error, but

```
   mysqli_stmt::execute()
```

keeps returning null, as opposed to returning false as the documentation says it should, leading me to believe that there is a syntax error in the query. Again, $errno is 0 and $sqlstate is '00000' after the execute() call so it doesn't appear that an error occurred, but I'd still like to know how to access the query being stored in the mysqli_stmt object.

Comment: +1 I'm trying to get the same thing, but so far I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=263790.0, you really can't  get to the underlying query. In my opinion, this is a serious omission in the class definition. Pity...